# ERR Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.12) is not compatible with client (0.19.5)

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy a composer REST Server to use my Hyperledger network deployed onto the IBM Blockchain Starter Plan on IBM Cloud. I've deployed a network, which is running okay, and the REST server using the command:

`bx cf push art-ledger --docker-image ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server -c "composer-rest-server -c admin@art-ledger -n never -w true" -i 1 -m 256M --no-start --no-manifest`

I get a message back saying "there are no running instances of this app" which I think is as it should be. When I then run the start command:

`bx cf start art-ledger`

After a minute or so I get a FAILED message with a line in the log output as follows:

*ERR Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.12) is not compatible with client (0.19.5)*

If I ping the network with the command:

`composer network ping --card admin@art-ledger`

It does indeed indicate the composer runtime is 0.19.12.

I don't specify a version number in the push command and I assume I just get the latest (i.e. 0.19.5). I did try specifying 0.19.12 but that did not exist.

Comment: Thanks for that. You are right this now works.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my version numbers got mixed up and at some point I clearly installed a later version of the composer runtime (i.e. version 0.19.12) than the composer REST server (i.e. version 0.19.5). Need to re-install to ensure version numbers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server docker image.

The problem is that the composer client installed in the docker image you are using is the 0.19.5 (see [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmblockchain/composer-rest-server/tags/)) but the composer runtime is the 0.19.12 (not compatible with the 0.19.5).

My solution is to use the hyperledger/composer-rest-server docker image (see [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/composer-rest-server/tags/)), version 0.19.12.

To do this you must change your push command as follow:

> bx cf push art-ledger --docker-image
> hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.12 -c "composer-rest-server -c
> admin@art-ledger -n never -w true" -i 1 -m 256M --no-start
> --no-manifest

**Note:** if you are using a cloudant service to store network cards, you must update the *hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.12* docker image with the *@ampretia/composer-wallet-cloudant* package. You can do this with the following push command:

> bx cf push art-ledger --docker-image
> hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.12 -c "npm install -g @ampretia/composer-wallet-cloudant; composer-rest-server -c
> admin@art-ledger -n never -w true" -i 1 -m 256M --no-start
> --no-manifest

Hope this will help you